# Replace xticks with names

Tags: matplotlib, plot, xticks

I am working on the Spotify dataset from Kaggle. I plotted a barplot showing the top artists with most songs in the dataframe.
 But **the X-axis is showing numbers and I want to show names of the Artists**.

```
names = list(df1['artist'][0:19])

plt.figure(figsize=(8,4))
plt.xlabel("Artists")

sns.barplot(x=np.arange(1,20),
                y=df1['song_title'][0:19]);
```

*I tried both list and Series object type but both are giving error.*

[image]

**How to replace the numbers in xticks with names?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Imports

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
```

### Data

- Data from [Spotify - All Time Top 2000s Mega Dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/iamsumat/spotify-top-2000s-mega-dataset)

```py
df = pd.read_csv('Spotify-2000.csv')
titles = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['Artist'])['Title'].count()).reset_index().sort_values(['Title'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
titles.rename(columns={'Title': 'Title Count'}, inplace=True)

# titles.head()

             Artist  Title Count
              Queen           37
        The Beatles           36
           Coldplay           27
                 U2           26
 The Rolling Stones           24
```

### Plot

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
chart = sns.barplot(x=titles.Artist[0:19], y=titles['Title Count'][0:19])
chart.set_xticklabels(chart.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Trenton! Worked beautifully. One small question though - i usually get the code auto fill for any object but set_xticklabels wasn't appearing for chart in my Jupyter notebook. Any idea why so?

Comment: Auto complete in Jupyter leaves something to be desired.  I did this in Jupyter too.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I didnt know this, although now it seems stupid not to do so in hindsight!

1. Pass names(or string labels) in the argument for X-axis.
2. **use plt.xticks(rotate=90) so the labels don't overlap**

[image]